# Log en Base de datos

Tags: sql-server

Hola expertos tengo una consulta y duda porque es primera vez que lo veo en una base de datos, les explico tengo una base de datos que tiene 3 archivos de Log, no se si esto es normal o si son creadas por el SQL o son creadas manualmente lo malo de esto es que si el principal tiene 5 Gb las otras dos tiene el mismo espacio.
Les adjunto una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería me pudiera ampliar esta duda o si esto es normal dado que en otras bases de datos solo existe un archivo de Log.

Agradeciendo su ayuda y tiempo en responder
Saludos

Comment: `Data` es log? Te creo que los últimos 4 son logs, pero [Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver16)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los archivos fueron creados manualmente. La recomendación general es solo tener un archivo de log en cada base de datos. Internamente, se crearán automáticamente varios archivos virtuales de log. Esos sí deben de ser varios pero no demasiados.

El log debe tener un tamaño adecuado para manejar las operaciones normales de la base de datos. Si crece demasiado es porque no se están realizando los respaldos de log adecuados. Si no se le va a dar mantenimiento, es mejor verificar que el tipo de recuperación de la base de datos sea simple. El problema con ese cambio es que se pierde la posibilidad de recuperar la base de datos a cualquier momento en el tiempo.

Comment: Gracias Luis por tu pronta respuesta, consulta es posible eliminar esos archivos de Log, existe alguna solucion para dejar solo el Log nativo ?

Comment: Sí, puedes eliminar los archivos de log adicionales. Pero me parece que tienes que cambiar el modo de recuperación a simple antes de hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias Luis por tus aclaraciones y voy investigar un poco mas sobre eliminar los archivos de log que están de mas.